# Write a function that calculates how old a person would have been if he was born on leap year(f.e. 29.2.2000)

Tags: c

My programs job is to check if a given date of birth is valid and in case if the day and month of birth is 29.2,then the program loops if the the given year of birth is not a leap year. Once the leap year has been entered, then the program calculates how old a person would have been if the person celebrated its birthday only on those leap years on 29.2.( Dan means day, mjesec means month and godina means year in my native language).My programs problem is that when I enter a leap year and exit the loop,my function does not get called and my program returns nothing.

```
int main()
{
printf("Unesi datum rodenja:    \n");
int dan,mjesec,godina,k;
scanf("%d %d",&dan,&mjesec);
if(dan==29&&mjesec==2)
{
    printf("Unesite neku prijestupnu godinu:   \n");
    scanf("%d",&godina);
    while(godina%4!=0&&godina%100==0||godina!=2000)
    {
        printf("Molim vas unesite godinu koja je prijesupna:   \n");
        scanf("%d",&godina);
        if(godina%4==0&&godina%100!=0||godina==2000)
        {
            k=provjera(dan,mjesec,godina);
            printf(k);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    printf("Unesite neku godinu:  \n");
    scanf("%d",&godina);
    k=provjera(dan,mjesec,godina);
    printf(k);
}
}

int provjera(int dan,int mjesec,int godina)
{
int i=2020,c;
if(godina>=1900 && godina<=9999)
{
    if(mjesec>=1 && mjesec<=12)
    {
        if((dan>=1 && dan<=31) && (mjesec==1 || mjesec==3 || mjesec==5 || mjesec==7 || mjesec==8 || mjesec==10 || mjesec==12))
        {
            printf("Datum je validan i godina nije prijestupna\n");
        }
        else if((dan>=1 && dan<=30) && (mjesec==4 || mjesec==6 || mjesec==9 || mjesec==11))
        {
            printf("Datum je validan i godina nije prijestupna\n");
        }
        else if((dan>=1 && dan<=28) && (mjesec==2))
        {
            printf("Datum je validan i godina nije prijestupna\n");
        }
        else if(dan==29 && mjesec==2 && (godina%4==0 && godina%100!=0||godina==2000))
        {
            c=(i-godina)%4;
            printf("Datum je validan i godina je prijestupna i ovoliko je osoba stara:  %d",c);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Uneseni dan je nemoguc za mjesec u kojem ste rodeni\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Uneseni mjesec je nemoguc");
    }
}
else
{
    printf("Godina je nemguca\n");
}

}
```

Comment: My programs problem is that when I enter a leap year and exit the loop,my function does not get called and my program return nothing.Sorry for not mentioning the problem.

Comment: Did you try to run your program line by line in a debugger while monitoring the values of all variables to see where exactly your program is not behaving as expected?

Comment: You may want to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)